# how to replace 2 double quotes in a file

Tags: c#

I have 2 double quotes that need to be replaced by a single double quote.

I am using this method:

```
private static void ReplaceTextInFile(string originalFile, string outputFile, string searchTerm, string replaceTerm)
{
    string tempLineValue;
    using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(originalFile))
    {
        using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            using (StreamWriter outputWriter = File.AppendText(outputFile))
            {
                while (null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    outputWriter.WriteLine(tempLineValue.Replace(searchTerm, replaceTerm));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and calling it this way

```
ReplaceTextInFile(file, file + "new", (char)34 + (char)34, (char)34);
```

the error i am getting is

```
Error   4   Argument '3': cannot convert from 'int' to 'string' 

and  Error  5   Argument '4': cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `ReplaceTextInFile(file, file + "new", "\"\"", "\"");`

Answer (score 4):

`(char)34+(char)34` is an `int`, with value 68.
The function is expecting a string.

I would pass `"\"\""`
*(escaping each double-quote with a back-slash)*

```
ReplaceTextInFile(file, file + "new", "\"\"", "\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling this method with an `Int32` (`char + char` == `int`) and a `Char`, not two `string` values.  Why not just use?:

```
ReplaceTextInFile(file, file + "new", "\"\"", "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

The function expects four `string`s.  You pass two `string`s, and then an `int`, and then a `char`.

Adding two `char`s results in an `int`.  You can't concatenate chars, it makes no sense as a `char` represents an *individual* character, so the result is an `int`.

The last one is a straight cast to `char` where a `string` is expected, that seems obvious enough.